# How to pass field values to apex class by command button?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I need to pass id field value to apex class to delete that row by using command button.

**Class:**

```
public class search_delete
{
public string id {get;set;}
public list<account> acc{get;set;}
public search_delete()
{
    acc = new list<account>();        
    acc = [SELECT id,name,phone,industry from account];

}
public void delete_record()
{

acc = [SELECT name,phone,industry from account where id = :id];

delete acc;
}
}
```

**VP:**

```
<apex:page controller="search_delete" >
 <apex:form >
     <apex:pageBlock >
         <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!acc}" var="a">
         <apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!a.Phone}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!a.Industry}"/>         
         <apex:column >
             <apex:commandButton value="Delete" Action="{!delete_record}">
                 <apex:param name="accId" value="{!a.id}"/>
             </apex:commandButton>
         </apex:column>
         </apex:pageBlockTable>
     </apex:pageBlock>     
 </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Now i need to pass id value to apex class from Vp page by the click of delete button.
[My Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTVRA.png)

Answer (score 1):

use the assignto property of apex command button.

```
<apex:page controller="search_delete" >
<apex:form >
 <apex:pageBlock >
     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!acc}" var="a">
     <apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!a.Phone}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!a.Industry}"/>         
     <apex:column >
         <apex:commandButton value="Delete" Action="{!delete_record}">
            <apex:param name="accId" value="{!a.id}" assignto="{!idchosen}/>
         </apex:commandButton>
     </apex:column>
     </apex:pageBlockTable>
 </apex:pageBlock>     
</apex:form>
```

```
public class search_delete
{
public string id {get;set;}
public string idchosen {get;set;}
public list<account> acc{get;set;}
public search_delete()
{
  acc = new list<account>();        
 acc = [SELECT id,name,phone,industry from account];

}
public void delete_record()
{

acc = [SELECT name,phone,industry from account where id = :idchosen];

delete acc;
}
}
```